# Lambda can't connect to RDS in the same VPC and subnet

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-aurora-serverless, sst

I'm using a Lambda via the `Script` and `Function` constructs to run database migrations against an `RDS` instance. However, the Lambda function can't connect to the RDS cluster despite being in the same VPC and subnet according to SST configuration. Here are the relevant parts of the configuration:

```js
function VpcStack({stack, app}: StackContext) {
    const vpc = new Vpc(stack, `myapp-${app.stage}-vpc`, {
        subnetConfiguration: [
            {
                name: 'private',
                subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            }
        ]
    })

    return {vpc}
}

function DatabaseStack({stack, app}: StackContext) {
    dependsOn(VpcStack)

    const database = new RDS(stack, 'database', {
        engine: 'postgresql13.9',
        scaling: {
            autoPause: false,
            minCapacity: 'ACU_2',
            maxCapacity: app.stage === 'production' ? undefined : 'ACU_2'
        },
        defaultDatabaseName: 'myapp',
        cdk: {
            cluster: {
                clusterIdentifier: `myapp-cluster-${app.stage}`,
                vpc: use(VpcStack).vpc,
                vpcSubnets: {
                    subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
                }
            }
        }
    })

    return {database}
}

function DatabaseMigrationStack({stack}: StackContext) {
    dependsOn(VpcStack)
    dependsOn(DatabaseStack)

    // Perform database migrations
    new Script(stack, 'migrations', {
        onUpdate: new Function(stack, 'migrate', {
            handler: 'sst/migrations/src/index.migrate',
            nodejs: {
                format: 'esm',
                install: ['pg', 'postgres-migrations'],
                minify: false
            },
            copyFiles: [{from: 'packages/schema/migrations'}],
            runtime: 'nodejs18.x',
            environment: getDatabaseEnvironment(),
            timeout: '5 minutes',
            vpc: use(VpcStack).vpc,
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            },
            enableLiveDev: false
        })
    })
}

function getDatabaseEnvironment() {
    const {database} = use(DatabaseStack)

    return {
        DB_HOST: database.clusterEndpoint.hostname,
        DB_PORT: database.clusterEndpoint.port.toString(),
        DB_NAME: database.defaultDatabaseName,
        DB_USER:
            database.cdk.cluster.secret
                ?.secretValueFromJson('username')
                .toString() ?? '',
        DB_PASS:
            database.cdk.cluster.secret
                ?.secretValueFromJson('password')
                .toString() ?? ''
    }
}
```

Here's the migration code before being transpiled to JS:

```js
import path from 'path'
import {migrate as pgmigrate, type MigrateDBConfig} from 'postgres-migrations'
import url from 'url'

declare const process: {
    env: {
        DB_HOST: string
        DB_PORT: string
        DB_NAME: string
        DB_USER: string
        DB_PASS: string
    }
}

export async function migrate() {
    const dbConfig = {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASS,
        ensureDatabaseExists: true,
        defaultDatabase: 'postgres'
    } satisfies MigrateDBConfig

    await pgmigrate(
        dbConfig,
        path.resolve(
            path.dirname(url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)),
            '../../../packages/schema/migrations'
        )
    )
}
```

After about 130s I get this error:

```json
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.142.195:5432",
  "trace": [
    "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.142.195:5432",
    "    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)"
  ]
}
```

What would be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this as follows:

1. In `DatabaseStack`, I added the following:

   ```js
   database.cdk.cluster.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(
       Port.tcp(database.clusterEndpoint.port)
   )
   ```
2. In `DatabaseMigrationStack`, I separated out the `Function` (called `scriptFunction`) and added the following:

   ```js
   const {database} = use(DatabaseStack)

   scriptFunction.connections.allowTo(
       database.cdk.cluster,
       Port.tcp(database.clusterEndpoint.port)
   )
   ```